# how to browse to a external url from turbogears/cherrypy application?

Tags: python, url-routing, cherrypy, turbogears

I am writing a tinyurl clone to learn turbogears. I am wondering how do i redirect my browser to the external website (say www.yahoo.com) from my cherrypy/turbogears app?

I googled about it, but could not find much useful info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just raise a HTTPRedirect exception, which lives in the cherrypy namespace. Like this:

```
raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect("http://www.yahoo.com")
```

Comment: Thanks.... works like a charm (for the urls starting with protcols specified explicitly)